# Is split view (UISplitViewController) possible in landscape mode for non plus size IPhones like IPhone 5, 6, 8 etc.?

Tags: ios, iphone, uisplitviewcontroller, swift4, landscape-portrait

I am having Master-Detail template containing UISplitViewController. 
For plus size Iphone landscape mode, splitviewcontroller automatically splits the view in 2 parts. Left side as Master view controller and right side with detailed viewcontroller.

This scenerio dosen't work with IPhone 5,6,8,X, it works for plus size like IPhone 6+ , 8 + etc.

Below is the code for SplitView delegate method.

```
func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController:UIViewController, onto primaryViewController:UIViewController) -> Bool 


    guard let secondaryAsNavController = secondaryViewController as? UINavigationController else { return false }
    guard let topAsDetailController = secondaryAsNavController.topViewController as? DetailViewController else { return false }
    if topAsDetailController.selectedEvent == nil {
        // Return true to indicate that we have handled the collapse by doing nothing; the secondary controller will be discarded.
        return true
    }
    return false
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation, it looks like possible:

> In a horizontally regular environment, the split view controller
>   presents its view controllers side-by-side whenever possible. In a
>   horizontally compact environment, the split view controller acts more
>   like a navigation controller, displaying the primary view controller
>   initially and pushing or popping the secondary view controller as
>   needed. You can also ask the split view controller to prefer a
>   specific arrangement by assigning a value to the **preferredDisplayMode**
>   property.

Try set the `preferredDisplayMode` to `allVisible` or `primaryOverlay` if first one doesn't work.

Comment: "allVisible" option is not working. I will check "primaryOverlay" option, hope it works, thanks for your help.

Comment: Both the options are not working :(. Is there any other configuration to make it work? - @brigadir

Comment: @Bhumika looks like there is no trivial way. Maybe hacking split view controller can solve the problem, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42772650/326017